# attempt to right click on a hyperlink in safari causes safari to freeze

Tags: macos, finder, safari, catalina, performance

I have my macbook pro 2013 model with macOS updated to Catalina, everytime I try to right click on a hyperlink in the safari browser , safari freezes then I had to force quit.

[image]

my safari browser also freezes when I try to open file dialog box.  I have taken the above screenshot from activity monitor.

any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

We can look at a system-wide stackshot to try to understand why the open panel XPC service hangs:

1. Run the following *Terminal* command to enable kernel symbolication: `sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`. Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a permission error, you will first need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection). You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. **Reboot your machine** and don’t open any apps except for *Terminal*.
3. In *Terminal*, enter the following command, press <kbd>Return</kbd>, type in your password, but **do not press <kbd>Return</kbd> again yet**: `sudo spindump -reveal -noProcessingWhileSampling`
4. Open Safari and start browsing as normal. Go ahead and reproduce the failing condition at this point.
5. Once the hang occurs, go to the *Terminal* window where you entered your password and press <kbd>Return</kbd> so that the command begins to execute. Do not do anything else on the computer while it's running, otherwise you will distort the data collection.
6. After waiting for >10 seconds to collect a sample and another minute or two to symbolicate and format, you’ll get a file in `/tmp/spindump.txt` that contains a stackshot of every process.
7. Upload the file to [PasteBin](https://www.pastebin.com) or some equivalent place and add the link to it to your original question.

Comment: running the command described in step 1 gives me this error: `Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) not permitted` !

Comment: @ChangZhao As I mentioned in step 1, this means you need to disable SIP

Comment: recovery mode is not starting even after holding around 2 minute then internet recovery mode starts up with spinning globe and wifi connection selector and after I login to my wifi it throws 2000F error.